# Existing project full of errors in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've received a simple VS Code console project and I intended to open it in my VS Code.

When I opened the *Program.cs* file, a notification appeared that I needed to restore the packages.
After it is done, every line is full of errors - *yet the project compiles and runs.*

[image]

Is this a bug?

**UPDATE**:

As of *version 1.31.1*, it is still an issue.

[image]

The contradiction between all the errors and the successful build… 
It still looks like a garage project, even after 1-2 years of development...

Comment: I have the same problem. It's a C# project that I often copy between two machines.  Every time I load it up on each machine, I get the prompt to restore (I'm transferring the project's folder between machines but not the `.nuget` folder from my user home folder).  Once the restore is done, I get numerous errors throughout the entire solution.  Closing VS code and reloading (or reloading the work space) fixes the problem and the errors simply disappear. I suspect the issue is caused by package version mismatches, but my `.csproj` file is very simple and doesn't specify explicit versions to use.